# How to get SDL 1.2 to show Error Message based on timed event?

Tags: sdl

OK so I am using SDL 1.2, and have created a planetary simulation of 2 bodies using it, I am near the end however, and there is one problem I can't seem to solve. in my program SDL reads the co-ordinates from a text file right, and then uses that text file to display the bodies on the screen afterwards. So my program can end one of two ways. What can happen is that either 
a) The two bodies collide, if this happens, the text file will read the co-ordinates "8888 8888 8888 8888" (x1, y1, x2, y2) 
b) One of the two bodies leaves the screen, if this happens, the text file will read the co-ordinates "9999 9999 9999 9999 " (x1, y1, x2, y2). 
Anyways, so what I want the program to do is when it sees those co-ordinates, close SDL, and paste the picture on the screen that contains the error message. What I have tried so far is:

```
 while (x11[x11.size() - 1] != 9999)
{
    //Start the frame timer
    fps.start();

    //If the user has Xed out the window
    if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        //Quit the program
        quit = true;
    }

    //Move the dots
    myDot.move();
    MoDot.move2();

    //Fill the screen white
    SDL_FillRect( screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF,    0xFF ));

    c++;

    //Show the dots on the screen
    myDot.show();
    MoDot.show2();

    //Update the screen
    if(SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Capping the frame rate
    if(fps.get_ticks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND)
    {
        SDL_Delay((1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND) - fps.get_ticks());
    }
}
```

As you can see, in that while loop, as long as x11 (which is co-ordinate x1) is not 9999, the while loop will continue to run, however what happens is that the program closes immediately! So in other words, the program closes within like a second, and you don't get to see the simulation, however, if i change that line to 
    while (quit == false)
the simulation shows, and when it gets to the point of the 8888 or 9999 co-ordinate it just crashes. 
So my question is 
How do i make the simulation stop when the co-ordinate being shown on the screen is 8888/9999 (cuz if i do what i did before, the program stops immediatley)

Comment: Can't you use a simple `break` statement?

Comment: it does the same thing the previous thing did, since C++ generates the  really fast, so even if i did like
"if (x coordinate = 88888)
 break;"
it ends just as quickly

Comment: Ok, so you need to add some "time" between the `break` and the actual quitting.

Comment: Ah, since the time would vary on the simulation, how would I determine the 'time' variable?

Comment: To clarify: when you say "the app crashes", it's not crashing, it's just exiting, right? If this is the case, _you_ define the time variable. Say, 5 seconds or something.

Comment: Yeahh, by crash I mean exiting, but since every simulation would be different depending on how many co-ordinates there are before either error (collision or OutOfScreen) happens, wouldn't the time for every simulation have to change as well?